# Can I remote desktop from XP SP3 to Windows Server 2K8 R2?

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2

When I try I get an error message saying that my computer does not support Network Level Authentication.  I am doing remote desktop across a VPN from a PC on a different domain.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to system properties, go to the "remote" tab and change the option to "Allow connections from computer running any version of Remote Desktop" to turn NLA off.  (On the server, that is)

- Right click on computer and click properties
- Click on the Remote settings link (left side) and you'll jump right to the remote tab of system properties, fyi.

Comment: Thank you.  Not quite sure why I didn't think of that.

Comment: Not a problem - I ran into this not two weeks ago so it was fresh in my mind.

Comment: Had the same problem late last year. The alternative it to update to something like Vista or Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably still using an older version of RDP client ... get the 6.x version and you should be good: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=6E1EC93D-BDBD-4983-92F7-479E088570AD&displaylang=en

Comment: I tried installing that and it told me that the service pack on the machine was more recent than the update I was trying to install.